# InsideSales Dialer - field security has to be bypassed?

Tags: api, administration

Anyone out there using the InsideSales dialer?

I recently was advised that, after I turned OFF an option I would never want on to begin with for most of our profiles...  **Edit Read Only Fields**...  [InsideSales](http://www.insidesales.com/) has told me I MUST have this turned on because their plugin must be able to write to all fields on the layout.  Huh?  This is of course insane.  I'm getting NO response from them for over a week as they took my request to fix this as an "enhancement request" and immediately marked it denied.

Anyone know of a way around using this permission, without REMOVING the field(s) from the layout?  They're there for the Sales Department to be able to see them, so...  :-P

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "solution" the vendor finally gave me, unless I can find the time to figure out the whole metadata-XML-API thing.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

So I have no idea why they would need that permission in order to run, but here's an idea for potentially moving some or all of the fields out of editable scope.

Move the read only fields to a inline visual force page. That why the data is displayed, but it's outside the scope of the detail layout.

No idea if that would work... just trying to think of a way to get around what seems like a scary permission requirement.

Also, Perhaps ReadyTalk?

Comment: ReadyTalk:  Doesn't look like it would be adequate, as InsideSales is a full fledge dialer and has a lot of functionality for "feeding" the sales team calls.  But thanks.

Comment: Field Permission issue: I finally got a response from the Dialer people yesterday, and apparently, for every field used on the layout I have to go:  Setup--SecurityControls--FieldAccessibility--(object) then by Field or Profile, alter the PageLayout setting to Read Only (again, PER FIELD, and that is hundreds in our case).  Urgh.

Comment: using the metadata API, you might be able to set those permissions via an XML File. If thats the case, you can search/replace within the xml to set them quickly.

Comment: Ah, enhancing my learning curve, are you... got it... and the research begins.  ;-)